# Google Analytics User-ID Session Unification, Goals

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have User-ID setup inside my GA with Session Unification ON

Now I want to track conversion rate from the users that visited the website and the ones that signed up

Right now inside my code when user signup I set his UserID and I trigger the event that he's signed up, and I can see that data inside User-ID View, but I cannot see a conversion rate between visitors and the ones that actually got signed up (since it's only displayed inside UserID View).

Would it make more sense that for the signup goal I just trigger the event that the user is signed up (and track conversion rate there)

And for the other goals that I need for the logged in users (like buying stuff and similar) I create the Goal inside User-ID View and track those conversions there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by conversion rate. If you are interested only for registered users you can see it in the User-ID view, if instead you are interested for all Analytics users you will have to use the standard view (and set the goals there too).

To avoid misunderstandings, I refer to the number of goals in general. User-ID will show only in User-ID view. However, you can send userId as custom dimension too, so you can read this value in standard view too.

Comment: So if I set up Goals inside all Analytics users they will show up for Users with an ID too? Because from what I saw it seems that those users are only showing inside User-ID View

Comment: I was referring to the number of goals in general. User-ID will show only in User-ID view. However, you can send userId as custom dimension too, so you can read this value in standard view too.

Comment: That makes sense! I added that custom dimension through GTM too, just after Using Measurement Protocol for triggering event I still don't see my data inside Reports, but they were showing inside the realtime, is it possible that I only tested with 1 user it will not show up? Or it just needs a lot of time to be processed. I'm struggling with the best way to test all this setup

Comment: If the custom dimension is at user level and the previous session is not closed you should see it later in analytics.

Comment: Yes I have a custom dimension userId on the User level, so those reports are going to take longer to collect data?

Comment: Not for the past.

Comment: Not sure I understand tbh

Comment: If you send custom dimension with user scope its valute is associated for the current session of that user and for the future sessions but not for past sessions (even if it is on user scope) .

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks!